# Why do we use Insertion Sort in the Bucket Sort?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, sorting

Bucket sort is a linear-time sort.

1. Why do we use insertion sort in it? We know that insertion sort takes $O(n^2)$ time.
2. Why can we not use any linear sort inside it?
3. As we see, when in each bucket we use insertion sort $O(n^2)$. How is bucket sort's total complexity $O(n)$?
4. Why do we not use a $O(n \log n)$ sort such as merge sort or quick sort?

Comment: Have you *read* the analysis? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Also, you want some $\Omega$s in your post. Your real question is: "How can Bucket Sort have expected running time in $\Theta(n)$ on a certain input class when it calls Insertion Sort repeatedly, which has expected running time in $\Omega(n^2)$ on the same class?"

Comment: Yes , i have read the analysis, i have done the proof.  What do you mean , ?I have tried?  what do you think after reading my question,you dont understand

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking the question. What specifically do you not understand in the proof? I should be immediately clear that the answers are: 1) It does not matter. 2) We can. 3) See analysis. 4) Because it would be slower. (Okay, maybe 4) does not follow immediately; that one requires broader knowledge.) If you don't get to these, there must be something you don't understand in the analysis -- and *that's* what you should ask about.

Comment: People have understood my question , and you also . So what is the fault. 
Dont be criticize. give me answer, if you can .

Comment: Your response time indicates that you have not spent one minute's thought on my comment. Literally. I (as a user) will not tolerate that. You ask a poor question, hence I downvote. I will not help you outsource your own thinking process.

Comment: 1)It does not matter. 2) We can. 3) See analysis. 4)  . Very good answer. 
Why do we use insertion sort??? see it again. 
What happened if we use linear sort in it?
i know in proof,  after using insertion sort, they proved that it take O(n). 
but how a O(n2) converted to O(n).  or if each bucket take O(n2) . then all buckets should take O(n2). 
4th i have understood .

Comment: Other thing,  What is the meaning of Uniform distribution between interval ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each bucket has $O(1)$ things, then insertion sorting the buckets takes time $O(n)$.

As a more practical matter, the algorithm you use to sort small lists of things should be chosen because it's fast at sorting small lists of things, not for its asymptotic performance on large lists of things. And insertion sort seems to be the popular choice for this task.

An implementation of bucket sort that produces buckets with many elements should indeed use some other method (e.g. bucket sort again) to sort the buckets.

Comment: Its not proper answer. If each bucket has o(n) things..? How. Mostly impossible. Some Buckets will have more than one element. So if it. Then on it insertion sort take o(n2). How will be total complexity O(n)? And address the other questions also.

Comment: The important thing is that -- for the input class and random distribution used to sell Bucket Sort -- the buckets are "small" *in expectation* (iirc, even with high probability).

Comment: @JawwadRafiq You need to keep pestering people who are trying to help you and stop to think and absorb the answer(s). If you can't understand the answer(s), as seems to be the case, you need to start over some chapters earlier.